# Cleaning badly formed Dates - using RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I am parsing some date from a 3rd party source, unfortunately some are badly formed.  What would be the best way of *cleaning/sanitising* them?

E.g.

> Wednesday 20July -> Wednesday 20July
>
> Tuesday20 July -> Tuesday 20 July

once I've got these I'm just converting them using

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse("Wednesday 20 July");
```

What would be the best way to convert these malformed dates?

I did have a play with RegEx, but I'm no expert

```
Regex regEx = new Regex("[0-9][a-zA-Z]");
Match match = Regex.Match("Wednesday 20July", "[0-9][a-zA-Z]");
```

I wasn't sure how to insert a space in the correct place once I had found a match.

Comment: `Wednesday 20July` shouldn't be a problem with `Parse`, well the other one would fail as 20 July is not Tuesday !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could insert a space between a digit and a letter (or between a letter and a digit) like this:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)", " ");
```

`(?<=\d)` checks if the previous character is a digit.

`(?=\p{L})` checks if the following character is a letter.